# Is there a method to include acf images in Wordpress import/export

Tags: php, wordpress, export, advanced-custom-fields

I just exported 175 entries from one wordpress site to another, each with two  Advanced Custom Fields custom image fields not realizing that they were not included by default.

I have not found an answer or plugin that would allow one complete migration.

I am looking for a solution, or even a method that might be easier than simply uploading all the acf images.